# Plotting a variable and a function

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a figure, I have defined my variable and my function, I just don't know why it gives me an empty plot

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np

import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num= 1e13
nuM= 1e16
N= 100

def f(nuj):
    return nuj**2

for j in range(N):
    nuj = num*(nuM/num)**(j/N)
    print nuj

print f(nuj)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim(1e10, 1e20)
plt.ylim(1e27, 1e33)        
plt.plot(nuj, f(nuj))
plt.show()
```

Comment: In you code nuj is a scalar. So it only retains a single float value after the loop. So you see a single point in the plot. Declare nuj as an array of zeros like nuj = np.zeros(N) and then add an index in your loop statement like nuj[j] = num*(nuM/num)**(j/N). Then you should see the plots properly.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually define the values to plot directly as numpy array.

```
nuj = num*(nuM/num)**(np.arange(N)/N)
```

This ensures to have all the values present in the plot, instead of only a single one.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num= 1e13
nuM= 1e16
N= 100

def f(nuj):
    return nuj**2

nuj = num*(nuM/num)**(np.arange(N)/N)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim(1e11, 1e18)
plt.ylim(1e26, 1e33)        
plt.plot(nuj, f(nuj))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I just have a question just to understand better, when I am defining the range for my nuj, why python doesn't give all the values to it? what if I put the plot code in the loop? it still doesn't work

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "give all values to it". In the code from the question you redefine `nuj` to be a single number in each loop step. After the loop finishes, `nuj` is the last loop step's value. That is why you do not want to use a loop here.